# How to use GpuDelegate in case of no OpenCL found in Android Device?

Tags: java, android, opencv, opencl, tensorflow-lite

I am very new to Android ,I am making CV application which uses tensorflow lite 'GpuDelegate'.
it works perfectly fine on Redmi 8A cause device supported OpenCl while when i installed in  Infinix Hot 8 lite , it crashes with this error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply
> delegate: Can not open OpenCL library on this device - dlopen failed:
> library "libOpenCL.so" not found
> Falling back to OpenGL
> TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: No EGL error, but eglChooseConfig failed.
> TfLiteGpuDelegate Prepare: delegate is not initialized
> Node number 69 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to prepare.
> Restored original execution plan after delegate application failure.

I want to know , if there is any alternate of OpenCl or could i use this library in my app and not from the system files.

my Infinix mobile device has Oreo Android Version

Using Open CV 3.4.14 version

Comment: The [Infinix Hot 8 lite](https://www.gsmarena.com/infinix_hot_8_lite-9927.php) appears to be an Android Go edition phone which may not have all of the features of regular Android due to smaller amount of RAM. See: [Does Android support OpenCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26795921/295004)